# Помогите исправить Лексические ошибки

Tags: лексика

Исправьте лексические ошибки.
1. Я хочу уделить ваше внимание на это. 2. Его угрозы обретают вполне кон-кретное содержание. 3. Для получения путевок необходимо предоставить справку от врача. 4. В поданных в суд документах сквозила решительность добиться взы-скания с корпорации материального ущерба. 5. Необходимо к началу года для из-готовления опытных образцов подготовить и запустить в производство техниче-скую документацию новой буровой установки. 6. Естество природы в моде прояв-ляется путем широкого использования всех оттенков и цветов земля и окружающе-го нас природного мира. 7. Взяткодатие наказывается так же сильно, как и взяткоб-ратие.

Comment: Предложите, пожалуйста, свой вариант, а мы исправим, если будет нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Как славно, что Вы не просите объяснять ***почему***.

---

> 1. Я хочу уделить ваше внимание на это, -

*обратить* вместо *уделить*.

> 2. Его угрозы обретают вполне конкретное содержание, -

ой, ну тут всё не по-людски, *угрозы, обретающие содержание,* кошмар какой, хотя и всё понятно; возможны варианты, в частности: *Его угрозы становятся вполне конкретными.*  (Это если уж так необходим упор на конкретике угроз, друзья по разуму меня поправят.)

> 3. Для получения путевок необходимо предоставить справку от врача, -

*представить*, то есть предъявить.

> 4. В поданных в суд документах сквозила решительность добиться взыскания с корпорации материального ущерба, -

апарте: решительность может сквозить в художественной литературе с уклоном в фельетон, в официозе же - но пассаран, невермор; возможны варианты, в частности *явствовала* (это вместо *сквозила*-то). Да! И не *решительность*, а *решимость*, паронимы это!

> 5. Необходимо к началу года для изготовления опытных образцов подготовить и запустить в производство техническую документацию новой
>      буровой установки, -

ну как документацию запустить в производство; просто убрать к чертям этот запуск: *Для изготовления опытных образцов новой буровой установки необходимо к началу года подготовить техническую документацию* (но тут, чтобы вмешиваться с редактурой, нужно понимать, кто на ком стоял; образцы *для* буровой установки?).

> 6. Естество природы в моде проявляется путем широкого использования всех оттенков и цветов земл**и**

(Вы списали с неоткорректированного тугамента; я проверила)

> и окружающего нас природного мира, -

тут псевдонабор псевдосмыслов:

естество - это и есть основное природное свойство (тавтология);
проявляется путём - словоблудие (канцеляризм?);
оттенки и цвета поменять местами - в порядке убывания важности;
земли и окружающего нас природного мира (нипонял-юмора-в-чём-дело, земля-планета плюс космос?), в общем, переписываем:

*Мир природы* [The Natural World] *проявляется в моде всеми цветами и оттенками ойкумены* (? - не настаиваю).

> 7. Взяткодатие наказывается так же сильно, как и взяткобратие, -

вот это я обожаю - ёмкие неологизмы, выражающие общую тенденцию языка к экономии средств, но - нет таких слов (плакайу); есть взяткодатель и взяточник, а процессы будут называться ску-у-ушно:

*Дача взятки наказывается так же серьёзно, как и получение взятки*

(мздоимство и устар. лихоимство).

Источник: [Давать взятку стало вдвое опаснее, чем брать](http://ppt.ru/news/126153).